# Authenticate with Firebase Using Email Link in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, email, firebase-authentication, localhost

my first question on stack overflow.

I'm currently working on a web application where I'm using Firebase for user authentication. I've encountered an issue related to email verification using Firebase authentication.

I am not receiving the authentication email in my inbox.

I am able to sign users in using email, google and facebook. I would like to be able to verify user emails. I am using firebase serve --only hosting and firebase serve --only hosting.

My goal is to allow users to verify their email addresses through the Firebase authentication process. I've referred to the Firebase documentation, specifically the guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth, and I'm using the actionCodeSettings as provided in the documentation. I am not receiving any error messages in the console log.

MY current code:

```
const actionCodeSettings = {
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/',
  handleCodeInApp: true,
  iOS: {
    bundleId: 'com.example.ios'
  },
  android: {
    packageName: 'com.example.android',
    installApp: true,
    minimumVersion: '12'
  },
  dynamicLinkDomain: 'example.page.link'
};

const createAccount = async () => {
  hideRegistrationState(); 

  const emailInputReg = document.getElementById('input-Email').value;
  const passwordInputReg = document.getElementById('input-Password').value;

  try {
    const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, emailInputReg, passwordInputReg);
    const user = userCredential.user;

    await sendSignInLinkToEmail(auth, emailInputReg, actionCodeSettings).then(() => {
      window.localStorage.setItem('emailForSignIn', emailInputReg);
    });
    
    // Clear registration error messages
    hideLoginErrorReg();

    // Show successful registration message
    showRegistrationState(user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`There was an error: ${error}`);
    console.log("Email Verifications Send");
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    showLoginErrorReg(error);
  }
}
```